# Why would this cast fail? - Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, casting, unreal-engine4

What I'm trying to do is read a series of paths from a data table, load those assets, and sort them by what type of asset they are so I can modify each differently.

So from these asset paths I need to separate out which are static meshes, actor blueprints, editor utility widgets, etc.  For some reason when I go to split up the blueprints though, the cast to UBlueprint always fails.

Btw, this is in the startup module of an editor plugin with the loading phase as PostEngineInit.  I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

```
for (FToolData Tool : ToolCategories[i]->Tools)
{
    
    FStringAssetReference AssetPath(Tool.AssetPath);
    UObject* Asset = AssetPath.TryLoad();

    if (IsValid(Asset))
    {
        UBlueprint* BlueprintAsset = Cast<UBlueprint>(Asset);

        if (IsValid(BlueprintAsset))
        {
            TSubclassOf<UObject> Parent = BlueprintAsset->ParentClass;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

I'm also sure that Asset is a UBlueprint.  I can see that it's parent class is Actor right there, but for some reason BlueprintAsset still isn't valid.

[image]

Comment: The `Cast<UBlueprint>(Asset)` is not standard, and presumably something defined in your program or in a library you are using.    Unless you describe what it is, nobody can explain why it fails.

Comment: "*when I go to split up the blueprints though, the cast to UBlueprint always fails*" - fails HOW exactly?  Is it a compile-time failure, or a runtime failure? Is there an error message?

Comment: @Peter 
Sorry I don't use stack overflow much.  I thought tagging it with Unreal Engine would specify this is Unreal. Fixed it in the question.

Comment: `IsValid` almost certainly isn't doing what you expect. If you step into it, it's probably a version that takes a bool or something (pointers are implicitly convertible so the compiler won't let you know this is happening by default). `if(Asset != nullptr)` or even `if(Asset)` are more than enough most of the time. The exception being when you actually care if something has been marked pending kill.

Answer (score 1):

George was right.  I had been treating `if(IsValid(Asset))` like it was interchangeable with `if(Asset)` or `if(Asset != nullptr)`.

Once I switched it to `!= nullptr` it worked fine.
I suppose it has something to do with being run at startup.